# Chrome extension send data between panel and content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I must admit the chrome api seems confusing to me. I'm trying to create an extension (page-action) in which the content script will send a message to the popup and vice versa.

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name":    "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.0",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["*://*.stackoverflow.com/*"],
    "js":         ["jquery.js", "content.js"],
    "run_at":     "document_idle",
    "all_frames": false
  }],

  "page_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension"
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
  if ((msg.from === 'content') && (msg.subject === 'showPageAction')) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
  }
});
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({ url: 'popup.html', type: 'panel' });
});
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  from:    'content',
  subject: 'showPageAction'
});
```

Now the tricky part:  Clicking a button in the popup which will send a message to the tab with the content script, the content script will run a function processing the dom and when done send a message back to the popup.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage